# how to pass messages in custom request classe in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

**Here is my request class on which i want to pass custom messages for form requests.**

I want to pass custom validation messages according to my custom rules.

```
<?php


namespace App\Http\Requests\Authenticate;

use App\Http\Requests\Request;

class AuthRequest extends Request
{

    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        // I want to return custom messages from here
        return [
            "email" => "required|email|exists:user,email",
            'password' => 'required',
        ];
    }

}
```

Any help appreciated. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is your answer. Add an extra function to pass messages.

```
public function messages()
{
    return [
        "required" => "The :attribute field is required.",
        'email' => 'The :attribute should be valid email.',
        'exists' => 'The :attribute already exists.'
    ];
}
```